# Creating a "generic" Tensorflow Android app with Python code

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, kivy

I created a Tensorflow image classification app in python 2.7 using Kivy and Pycharm. I used my own data to create a custom graph and labels file. The app works great and does what I want it to do. It took me months of learning and coding to get to this point. My last part of this "journey" has been trying to port the app to the android platform (I'd like to do Windows or a web app too -- but that does not seem to be a real option today . . .) I've created the Tensorflow Android Camera Demo app using Bazel and it worked fine on my Galaxy S5. However, after spending several long days searching all the references I could fine in Google searches, Packt (and other) books, and so on I am at an impasse. My question is does anyone in this forum have any advice on a method to create an Android app from a working Python app as I described? I would be really grateful for any help from someone who has done this.

Comment: You probably need to make a Tensorflow recipe for python-for-android. I don't know what would be required for this.

Comment: The issue I'm trying to resolve is how to create an Android (or other "stand alone" executable app) with the working project I created (in Pycharm). The basic problem is the import of tensorflow (in my python code), which isn't recognized when I try to build an app. So I guess my question might be restated to: How to I build my app using a method that will recognize and integrate Tensorflow (as an import) in the built app?

Comment: Tensorflow is a complicated module that will need compiling for the android environment, but I don't know what exactly needs doing or how it relates to the normal Tensorflow build. To make it work, you need to make a python-for-android recipe (http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) to tell python-for-android how to compile and include it in the APK. If you ask on the kivy support channels, we can help you try it, but I'm not aware of any preexisting Tensorflow recipe to work from.

Answer (score 0):

> I used my own data to create a custom graph and labels file

Since you have already trained your TensorFlow model, you can import it into an Android app relatively easily.

The [TensorFlow Android demo app](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) can now be built in Android Studio without using Bazel.  You should be able to replace the Inception v3 image classifier model with your own model.

Check out my blog post here for more information about how to use the  Java `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` class to interact with your pre-trained model:
https://medium.com/@daj/using-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-on-android-e747831a3d6

As for how to port a Python app to Android, I'm not aware of an easy way to do that.